# How to Creating Custom datagrid in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, xamarin.forms

Currently i am working in creating custom datagrid for displaying list of data as Grid.I got some sample source from [Github](https://github.com/yz1311/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid) .Based on sample source i have modified on my requirements. But I have some issues while accessing listview data
1. I can able to change the particular cell background colour when i tapped that particular cell.But need to get relevant row for some calculation.

2. I need to differentiate marked cell and unmarked cell. once i click the cell.
3. My question is how to get entire row data at that same time clicked cell differentiating for the calculation [Output Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbTdu.png)

Code Snap:

```
public class DataGrid : StackLayout
    {

        #region binding properties

      //  public static BindableProperty ItemClickCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, ICommand>(x => x.ItemClickCommand, null);


        public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderBackgroundProperty =
                             BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, Color>((p) => p.HeaderBackground, Color.Aqua);

        public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderTextColorProperty =
                            BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, Color>((p) => p.HeaderTextColor, Color.Black);

        public static readonly BindableProperty EvenRowBackgroundProperty =
                            BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, Color>((p) => p.EvenRowBackground, Color.White);

        public static readonly BindableProperty OddRowBackgroundProperty =
                             BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, Color>((p) => p.OddRowBackground, Color.White);

        public static readonly BindableProperty EvenRowForegroundProperty =
                            BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, Color>((p) => p.EvenRowForeground, Color.Black);

        public static readonly BindableProperty OddRowForegroundProperty =
                            BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, Color>((p) => p.OddRowForeground, Color.Black);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ColumnsProperty =
                            BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, ColumnCollection>((p) => p.Columns, null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, UpdateColumns);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
                            BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, IEnumerable>((p) => p.ItemsSource, null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, DrawDataGrid);

        public static readonly BindableProperty RowHeightProperty =
                            BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, double>((p) => p.RowHeight, 40);

        public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderHeightProperty =
                            BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, double>((p) => p.HeaderHeight, 40);

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsSortableProperty =
                            BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, bool>((p) => p.IsSortable, true);

        public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderFontSizeProperty =
                            BindableProperty.Create<DataGrid, double>((p)=>p.HeaderFontSize,13);

        private static void DrawDataGrid(BindableObject bindable, IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
        {
            if ((bindable as DataGrid).Columns.Count > 0 && !(bindable as DataGrid).hasInitialized)
                (bindable as DataGrid).InitilizeUI();
        }

        private static void UpdateColumns(BindableObject bindable, ColumnCollection oldValue, ColumnCollection newValue)
        {
            if (!(bindable as DataGrid).hasInitialized && newValue.Count > 0)
                (bindable as DataGrid).InitilizeUI();
        }

        #endregion

        #region properties
        public Color HeaderBackground
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(HeaderBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        public Color HeaderTextColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(HeaderTextColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderTextColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public Color EvenRowBackground
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(EvenRowBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EvenRowBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        public Color OddRowBackground
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(OddRowBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OddRowBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        public Color EvenRowForeground
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(EvenRowForegroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EvenRowForegroundProperty, value); }
        }

        public Color OddRowForeground
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(OddRowForegroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OddRowForegroundProperty, value); }
        }

        public IList ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public ColumnCollection Columns
        {
            get { return (ColumnCollection)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
        }

        public double HeaderFontSize
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(HeaderFontSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderFontSizeProperty,value); }
        }

        public double RowHeight
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(RowHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RowHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        public double HeaderHeight
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(HeaderHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderHeightProperty, value); }
        }
        public bool IsSortable
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSortableProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsSortableProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region fields

        bool hasInitialized = false;
        Dictionary<int, SortingOrder> SortingOrders;
        ListView listView;
        #endregion

        #region ctor
        public DataGrid()
        {
            SortingOrders = new Dictionary<int, SortingOrder>();

            this.Columns = new ColumnCollection();
            this.Padding = 5;
            this.Spacing = 0;
            this.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            this.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;


            listView = new ListView()
            {
                SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,

                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(GetRowTemplate),
             };

            //  listView.ItemTapped += this.OnItemTapped;
            listView.ItemTapped +=  (sender, e) =>
             {
                 if (e.Item != null)
                 {
                     var selectedItem = e.Item;
                 }

                // await  Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert();
             };


            listView.ItemSelected += (s, e) =>
            {
                listView.SelectedItem = null;
            };
        }
        #endregion

        //public ICommand ItemClickCommand
        //{
        //    get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(ItemClickCommandProperty); }
        //    set { this.SetValue(ItemClickCommandProperty, value); }
        //}

        //private void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    if (e.Item != null && this.ItemClickCommand != null && this.ItemClickCommand.CanExecute(e))
        //    {
        //        this.ItemClickCommand.Execute(e.Item);
        //        listView.SelectedItem = null;
        //    }
        //}


        public void InitilizeUI()
        {
            hasInitialized = true;

            if (IsSortable)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Columns.Count; i++ )
                    SortingOrders.Add(i, SortingOrder.NotDetermined);
            }

            listView.ItemsSource = ItemsSource;
            listView.RowHeight = (int)RowHeight;
            this.Children.Add(GetHeader());

            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
            {
                ScrollView sv = new ScrollView();
                sv.Content = listView;
                this.Children.Add(sv);
            }
            else
                this.Children.Add(listView);

        }

        protected virtual Grid GetHeader()
        {
            Grid header = new Grid()
            {
                HeightRequest = HeaderHeight,
                Padding = new Thickness(1),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowSpacing = 0,
                ColumnSpacing = 1,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
            };

            header.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(HeaderHeight, GridUnitType.Absolute) });

            foreach (var col in Columns)
            {
                header.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = col.Width });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                Label lb = new Label()
                {
                    Text = Columns[i].Title,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    TextColor = HeaderTextColor,
                    FontAttributes = Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes.Bold,
                    XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                    YAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                    LineBreakMode = Xamarin.Forms.LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
                    FontSize=HeaderFontSize,
                };

                StackLayout sl = new StackLayout()
                {
                    BackgroundColor = HeaderBackground,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    Children = { lb }
                };

                if (IsSortable)
                {
                    var orderingIcon = new Label()
                    {
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        Text = " ",
                    };

                    Columns[i].Params = orderingIcon;
                    sl.Children.Add(orderingIcon);

                    string property = Columns[i].DataProperty;
                    string title = Columns[i].Title;
                    var tgr = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                    tgr.Tapped += (s, e) => {
                        var col = Columns.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.DataProperty == property && x.Title == title);
                        SortItems(Columns.IndexOf(col)); 
                    };
                    sl.GestureRecognizers.Add(tgr);
                }
                header.Children.Add(sl);

                Grid.SetColumn(sl, i);
            }
            return header;
        }

        bool isEven = false;
        bool first = true;
        object GetRowTemplate()
        {
            KowalskiViewCell row = new KowalskiViewCell();
            Grid rowGrid = new Grid()
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
                RowSpacing = 0,
                ColumnSpacing = 1,
                Padding = new Thickness(1, first ? 1 : 0, 1, 1)
            };

            first = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Columns.Count; i++)
                rowGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = Columns[i].Width });
            int i1 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                i1++;
                ContentView cell = new ContentView()
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                    BackgroundColor = (isEven) ? EvenRowBackground : OddRowBackground
                };

                if(Columns[i].CellTemplate!= null)
                {
                    View v = Columns[i].CellTemplate.CreateContent() as View;
                    v.HorizontalOptions = Columns[i].HorizontalContentAlignment;
                    cell.Content = v;
                }

                else if (Columns[i].DataProperty != null)
                {
                    Label text = new Label()
                    {
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        HorizontalOptions = Columns[i].HorizontalContentAlignment,
                        TextColor = (isEven) ? OddRowForeground : EvenRowForeground,
                        FontSize = 12,
                    };

                    //Here implemeting Logic 

                    if (Columns[i].DataProperty == "Name" || Columns[i].DataProperty == "Goal" || Columns[i].DataProperty == "Achieved" || Columns[i].DataProperty == "Net")
                        text.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(Columns[i].DataProperty, BindingMode.TwoWay));

                    var tgr = new TapGestureRecognizer();

                    var property = Columns[i].DataProperty;


                var textval  =  text.GetValue(Label.TextProperty);

                    tgr.Tapped += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        if (property != "Name" && property != "Goal" && property != "Achieved" && property != "Net")
                        {
                            cell.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
                            text.FontSize = 24;
                            text.TextColor = Color.White;

                            text.Text = i1.ToString();
                        }
                    };
                    cell.GestureRecognizers.Add(tgr);

                    cell.Content = text;
                }

                rowGrid.Children.Add(cell);
                Grid.SetColumn(cell, i);
            }

            isEven = !isEven;
            row.View = rowGrid;
            return row;
        }

        private void SortItems(int propertyIndex)
        {
            if (ItemsSource == null || ItemsSource.Count <= 1)
                return;

            List<Object> item = new List<Object>();
            foreach (var itm in ItemsSource)
                item.Add(itm);

            List<Object> sortedItems;


            if (!IsSortable)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This DataGrid is not sortable");
            if (Columns[propertyIndex].DataProperty == null)

                throw new InvalidOperationException("Please set the DataProperty property of Column");
            if (SortingOrders[propertyIndex] != SortingOrder.Descendant)
            {
                int i = 0;
                var itm = item[0].GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(Columns[propertyIndex].DataProperty).GetValue(item[0]);
                if (itm is decimal)
                    i++;
                if (itm is double)
                    i++;
                sortedItems = item.OrderByDescending((x) => x.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(Columns[propertyIndex].DataProperty).GetValue(x)).ToList();
                SortingOrders[propertyIndex] = SortingOrder.Descendant;
                (Columns[propertyIndex].Params as Label).Text = "▼";
            }
            else
            {
                sortedItems = item.OrderBy((x) => x.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(Columns[propertyIndex].DataProperty).GetValue(x)).ToList();
                SortingOrders[propertyIndex] = SortingOrder.Ascendant;
                (Columns[propertyIndex].Params as Label).Text = "▲";
            }

            foreach (var column in Columns)
            {
                if ((column.Params as Label).Text!= null && Columns[propertyIndex] != column )
                    (column.Params as Label).Text = " ";
            }

            isEven = false;
            listView.ItemsSource = sortedItems;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's always good to show some code on what you have done

Comment: I added my source code here dav

Comment: `StackLayout` would have performance problems with many elements. I would advice against using it. ListView is much more performant. Maybe it would help: https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView  (there's source code there)

Answer (score 1):

The feature that you're trying to implement is already implemented in original repository[ [here](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid) ].

Realted pull request: [here](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid/pull/15)